# What you call someone who leaks information from a team?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

What you call someone who leaks information from a team or group. Like Spy.

Can you call him/her a "Rat"?

Thanks.

Comment: It might depend on whether the leak is deliberate or not, and whether what is leaked is seriously confidential and leaked to a competitor. I would not use "Rat" except for serious, deliberate betrayal for personal gain. That is, not for a careless blabbermouth. Which is a word you might use.

Comment: @DavidPugh: Precisely. This question, as it stands currently, is too broad. TesterDonkey, please tell us what context you're planning to use the word in.

Comment: For example, in a company or in an office one person in your team who acts normal with you always.. But he for his personal gain tells your superior or senior regarding the thing you share in your team (could be things bad about senior).

Comment: Depends on your point of view:  A source, a leak, a snitch, a rat, a whistle-blower, a mole, a canary, a fink, an informant, a stool pigeon, and several more.

Comment: I still like to use the slang "**nark**"

Comment: How come this sounds like a joke? You know, "what do you call a ----" format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first noun that came to my mind is **whistleblower**, but if you look up the thesaurus on Dictionary.com, there are plenty more such as **bigmouth**, **squealer** (to name a few that I'm familiar with), and **rat** is also there!

You can browse some other possible words following the link below:
http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/whistleblower

Comment: "Whistleblower" only applies if the team is doing something wrong/illegal.

Answer (score 2):

When several leaks take place over a period of time, then the individual doing the leaking is known as a [*mole*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?site=&source=hp&q=define+mole&oq=define+mole&gs_l=hp.3..0l10.780.2206.0.2411.12.10.0.0.0.0.354.1081.0j3j1j1.5.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..8.4.774.0.bSNzDrP104U).

The term was popularised in the works of [John Le Carré](http://www.johnlecarre.com/).  In *Tinker Tailor Soldier Spy*, much is made of the character Smiley searching for the mole in British Intelligence leaking information to the Soviets.

The term has become much more widespread in usage than as a spy and would be appropriate for any team.

Comment: a mole is someone who infiltrates an organization for the purpose of obtaining secret information for his actual employer. His purpose is not to "leak" information.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock it depends what "leak" means I suppose.  The most common meaning nowadays is "to make public", and that definitely doesn't fit with "mole".  But it could just mean "release", and if it's released only to that person's employers, then you could call them a mole.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a non-slang term, a good one might be *informer*, which *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) defines as follows:

> **informer** *n* (14c) **1 :**  one that imparts knowledge or news **2 :** one that informs against another; *specif* : one who makes a practice esp. for a financial reward of informing against others for violations of penal laws

Of course, in the example you give, the "reward" that the informer gets is preferment by the superior, and the metaphorical "violations of penal laws" are nothing more than criticisms of those in authority, but *informer* still seems apt. Another option is *tattletale* (again as defined in the *Eleventh Collegiate*):

> **tattletale** *n* (1888) one that tattles [in the sense of "to tell secrets"]: INFORMER

And yet another is *talebearer*:

> **talebearer** *n* (15c) one that spreads gossip or rumors; *also* : TATTLETALE

Yet another way to describe such a person is with the phrase "betrayer of confidences," meaning someone who participates in a no-holds-barred, everything-on-the-table discussion that has as one of its ground rules that what is said in the room stays in the room, and then breaks faith with that understanding by acting as a conduit of what was said in confidence, to nonparticipants.